# Java : Writing CSV in String format to CSV in a file

Tags: java, csv, file-io

A method returns a String in comma separated format. For example, the returned String can be like the one given below.

`Tarantino,50,M,USA\n Carey Mulligan,27,F,UK\n Gong Li,45,F,China`

I will need to get this String and write it into a CSV file. I'll have to insert a header and a footer for this file as well.

For example, when I open the file, the contents for the above data will be

```
Name,Age,Gender,Country
Tarantino,50,M,USA    
Carey Mulligan,27,F,UK
Gong Li,45,F,China
```

How do we do that ? Are there any open source libraries to do this task ?

Comment: Why do you need an extra library to write text to a file? Just write the header to the file, and since your string already has line breaks, simply write the string to the file.

Answer (score 1):

CSV format is not very well defined. You don't have to write headers for the file. Instead it is pretty SIMPLE format. Data values are separated using commas or semicolon or space etc.
You just have to write your own simple method that writes your string to a file on local computer using FileOutputStream or Writer in java.io package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as a learning example.
I used `BufferedReader` because he will take care about `line` separators, but you can also use [`#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method, and write the resulting tokens.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Tests {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file = new File("out.csv");
    BufferedWriter out = null;

    try {

      out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

      String string = "Tarantino,50,M,USA\n Carey Mulligan,27,F,UK\n Gong Li,45,F,China";

      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(string.getBytes())));
      String line;

      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        out.write(line.trim());
        out.newLine();
      }
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
      // log something
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally {
      if (out != null) {
        try {
          out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          // ignored
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple

```
String str = "Tarantino,50,M,USA\n Carey Mulligan,27,F,UK\n Gong Li,45,F,China";
PrintWriter  pr = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(new File("test.csv"), true));
String arr[] = str.split("\\n"); 
// splited the string by new line provided with the string
pr.println("Name,Age,Gender,Country"); 
// header written first and rest of data appended
for(String s : arr){
    pr.println(s);
}
pr.close();
```

don't forget to close the stream in finally block and handle the exception